# Asymptotic behavior of $n\sqrt n + n \log n$ & $\log_{100} n$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics

I have the following two functions

- $f(n) = n\sqrt n + n \log n$
- $\log_{100} n$

And I need to classify them into the followings:

- $O(n)$, and/or
- $O(n^2)$, and/or
- $O(n^3)$, and/or
- $O(n^{1.5})$, and/or
- $\omega(n)$, and/or
- $o(n\log n)$ (small o)
- $\theta(n^{1.5})$,

Regarding the $\theta(n^{1.5})$, I am grasping it's idea newly, where do these functions set in. Also, does the function $f(n) =n^{0.9999}$ belong to $\theta(n^{1.5})$.

I would appreciate your feedback, as from your answers I am building up the knowledge for these.

Comment: Am I supposed to define w(n) by myself?

Comment: it is possibly $\omega(n)$

Comment: Welcome back to [cs.SE]! You can use LaTeX to typset mathematics, rather than doing it manually with sup tag and some other weird stuff. I edited to show you how; we also have [a brief tutorial](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: @kelalaka, thanks for the hint. tony9099, please edit if I have not updated your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

- $\log_{100}n \in \mathcal{O}(log(n))$ since base change is a constant.

  - $\log n \in \mathcal{O}(n) $
  - $\log n \in \mathcal{O}(n^2) $
  - $\log n \in \mathcal{O}(n^3) $
  - $\log n \in \mathcal{O}(n^{3/2}) $
  - $\log n \not\in \mathcal{\omega}(n) $
  - $\log n \in \mathcal{o}(n \log n) $

This [table](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/98214/94479) gives the order;

First of all;

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n \sqrt n}{n \log n} = \infty$$ by using this;

- $f(n)= n\sqrt n + n\log n \in \mathcal{O}(n\sqrt n )$.

  - $ n\sqrt n \not\in \mathcal{O}(n)$
  - $n\sqrt n \in \mathcal{O}(n^2) $
  - $n\sqrt n \in \mathcal{O}(n^3) $
  - $n\sqrt n \in \mathcal{O}(n^{3/2}) $
  - $n\sqrt n \in \mathcal{\omega}(n) $
  - $n\sqrt n \not\in \mathcal{o}(n \log n) $,

Comment: Please remember that we're not a homework answering service. Answers that don't teach people how to solve the problem aren't very valuable at all.

Comment: Most questions of the for "Is this function big-O of this other function" can be flagged as duplicates of the one I marked. That question covers the general techniques and there's usually not much more to say, since the same functions tend to be used as examples each time.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks a lot for your input :) I have edited the question and added a new bound as well as a new function. I would appreciate if you can have a look :) (PS: this is not a homework)

Comment: Take the limit at WolframAlpha. That easy.